# Update multiple objects with Parse?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

How can you update multiple objects to Parse in a single query?

The code below is for a single entry.

How can I go about updating multiple values, which I get from an array?

```
 var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
 query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("xWMyZEGZ") {
 (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error != nil {
     println(error)
  } else if let gameScore = gameScore {
    gameScore["cheatMode"] = true
    gameScore["score"] = 1338
    gameScore.saveInBackground()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `saveAll*:` methods to save a batch of objects at once without calling save on each of them individually. Basically, you put all the objects you want to save into an array and then call `[PFObject saveAll:yourArray]` (just an example you can use `saveAllInBackground:` as well).

Here is some sample code in Objective-C, I am not very good with Swift but you probably can translate it easily.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[query findInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    NSMutableArray *saveAllOfMe = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (PFObject *object in results) {
        object[@"cheatMode"] = @(YES);
        object[@"score"] = @(1234);
        [saveAllOfMe addObject:object];
    }
    [PFObject saveAllInBackground:saveAllOfMe block:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        // Check result of the operation, all objects should have been saved by now
    }];
}];
```

https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/saveAllInBackground:block:

Comment: thanks for this. would you be able to help me out with some sample code with the example above

Comment: I added a short sample that should work. I wrote it from the top of my head and din't compile it, so it might need some tweaking :)